# ReentrantLock is not showing expected result

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, reentrantlock

Where is the problem? `ReentrantLock` is not showing expected result. Two threads are executing same time rather than waiting one thread.

```
class MyThread2 extends Thread{
    String name;
    ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();
    MyThread2(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void run(){
        do {
            try {
                if (reentrantLock.tryLock(20,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
                    System.out.println("executing : "+ name);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    reentrantLock.unlock();
                    break;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("waiting "+ name);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while (true);
    }
}

public class LockDemo2{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyThread2("Thread - 1").start();
        new MyThread2("Thread - 2").start();
    }
}
```

output:

```
executing : Thread - 1
executing : Thread - 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the same `ReentrantLock` in different threads, instead creating different locks.

Change the constructor to this :

```
ReentrantLock reentrantLock;
MyThread2(String name, ReentrantLock lock){
    this.name = name;
    this.reentrantLock = lock;
}
```

And pass the same lock to them:

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
new MyThread2("Thread - 1", lock).start();
new MyThread2("Thread - 2", lock).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different `ReentrantLock` on two different threads.
 @user6690200 solution is correct of using the same lock via the constructor.

Another solution is you can change your `ReentrantLock` to:

`private static final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();`

So that each instance of a different thread will always share only one object of your `ReentrantLock`.